# HTML template and using countdown timer

Tags: javascript, countdown

Hello friends i am making a coming soon 
HTML template and using countdown timer , 
i want to make time 
refresh automatically after 1 sec

i want to make the javascript execute atumatically

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

        <meta name="keywords" content="nineforo,9foro">
        <title>9foro | Coming soon</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="" type="text/css">
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Philosopher:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.countdown.pack.js"></script>
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->    
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () { 
                $('#countdown').countdown({until: new Date(2014, 5 - 1, 1)}); 
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <header>
            <h2>9fORO</h2>

        <section id="timer">
            <p>Estimated time remaining before official launch:</p>
            <div id="countdown"></div>
        </section>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: u may try using [window.setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_setinterval)

Answer (score 0):

Can not find your script `jquery.countdown.pack.js`. But you can try https://github.com/hilios/jQuery.countdown

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

        <meta name="keywords" content="nineforo,9foro">
        <title>9foro | Coming soon</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="" type="text/css">
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Philosopher:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.countdown.pack.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hilios/jQuery.countdown/master/dist/jquery.countdown.min.js"></script>
        <!--[if lt IE 9]> 
            <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->    
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () { 
                $('#countdown').countdown("2014/14/04",function(event){
                    $(this).html(event.strftime('%D days %H:%M:%S'));
                }); 
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <header>
            <h2>9fORO</h2>

        <section id="timer">
            <p>Estimated time remaining before official launch:</p>
            <div id="countdown"></div>
        </section>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```